# observing an Object in Runtime - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an object that I initialize on the `UIViewController` of my Screen with null.

The Object will get his Value on the Runtime.

I want to observe this Object and when it get Value I want run another Method on it.

I was Thinking about Firing event when it is not more null and listing on it somewhere on the Class.

But I don't know How or if this is a good idea.
Thanks.

Comment: Google for Objective C KVO (key value observing).

Comment: KVO is maybe overkill here - just use the setter if the object is a property of the vc.

Comment: no, it is not a property,  it really objects of a class. 
but by the way, do you have a link of  an Example How to observe Object using setter?

Comment: Well, the title and your comments sound like KVO but anyhow. I'll post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this using a property, try

```
@interface ...

@property (nonatomic,strong) SomeObject * obj;

@end

@implementation ...

// Setter of obj
// You can do this for all properties of course
- ( void ) setObj:( SomeObject * ) obj
{
  // Some logic e.g.
  if ( obj.x > 100 )
  {
    self.label.hidden = YES;
  }
  else if ( obj.x > 200 )
  {
    self.label.text = @"Too much";
  }

  // Here the setting takes place
  _obj = obj;     // Here _obj is the member and obj the new value
}

// Just for reference, this is the getter
- ( SomeObject * ) obj
{
  // Even here you can add logic, e.g.
  if ( ! _obj )
  {
    _obj = [[SomeObject alloc] initSomeDefault];
  }

  return _obj;
}
```

This is pretty stock standard Objective-C stuff. Look up a few references as well as this is often used to embed some logic and is easier than KVO. That said, KVO is very powerful.

Here is another suggestion, why not use `NSNotification`. Then you can post a notification inside the setter whenever the object is set and you can listen for that anywhere and take appropriate action. This is also used a lot to e.g. listen for when the keyboard appears.